# Java 8 Fork Streams for MapUntil

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've recently started playing with java streams.
Now i came up with

```
Stream<T> mapUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<T,T> mapFunc, Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate)
```

or a more general

```
Stream<T> applyUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate)
```

and thier naive implementions

```
Stream<T> mapUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<T,T> mapFunc, Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate){
    return applyUntil(in,in->in.map(mapFunc),predicate)
}
Stream<T> applyUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate){
    if(predicate.test(in)) return in;
    return applyUntil(func.apply(in),func,predicate);
}
```

Sadly, `mapUntil(stream,mapFunc,s->s.anyMatch(predicate))` results in  `IllegalStateException: Stream has already been operated on or closed`, which is logical, beacause I call `anyMatch` and `map` on the same stream. So I came up with a different implemention for `applyUntil`:

```
Stream<T> applyUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate){
    List<T> collected = in.collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(predicate.test(collected.stream())) return collected.stream()
    return applyUntil(func.apply(collected.stream(),func,predicate);
}
```

This has obviously lots of problems.

- It doesn't work for infinite (or very huge) streams. *In my specail case, thats acceptable, but it feels bad to claim this for such a general methode*
- It working against the intetion of streams, because all lazieness is lost - every data has to be calculated and stored due to `collect(Collectors.toList())`

I've tried to modify my code to eliminate the second problem, rewriting `applyUntil`:

```
Stream<T> applyUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate){
    List<T> collected = in.collect(Collectors.toList());
    return applyUntil(()->collected.stream(),func,predicate);
}
Stream<T> applyUntil(Supplier<Stream<T>> sup, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> pred){
    if(predicate.test(sup.get())) return sup.get();
    return applyUntil(()->func.apply(sup.get()),func,predicate);
}
```

This implemention does work - but is horribly slow, especially if you have a very expensive function. When I looked closer at it, I recognized why: it's calling  `predicate.test(collected.stream())`,`predicate.test(func.apply(collected.stream()))`, `predicate.test(func.apply(func.apply(collected.stream()))` and so on, resulting in  `O(n^2)` calls of `func`, compared to `n` needed calls. Thats not good.

In my naive world, there should be a better solution than those both. Something like that (just a quick draft, AddFirst - Exists are simple lazy implementations for MyStream. I miss a class like my Fork at the end of this code for default java Streams):

```
interface MyStream<T>{
    T get();
    boolean hasNext();
}
class Convert<T> implements MyStream<T>{
     Iterator<T> inner;
     pulic Convert(Interator<T> iter){
          inner=iter;
     }
     public boolean hasNext(){
          return inner.hasNext();
     }
     public T get(){
          return inner.get();
     }
class AddFirst<T> implements MyStream<T>{
     T item;
     MyStream<T> inner;
     boolean used;
     public AddFirst(T t, MyStream<T> prev){
         item=t;
         inner=prev;
         used=false;
     }
     public T get(){
          if(used) return inner.get();
          used=true;
          return item;
     }
     public boolean hasNext(){
         return !used || inner.hasNext();
     }

}
class Filter<T> implements MyStream<T>{
     Predicate<T> filter;
     MyStream<T> inner
     public Filter(Predicate<T> test, MyStream<T> prev){
         filter=test;
         inner=prev;
     }
     public T get(){
          while(true){
              T curr = inner.get(); //if !inner.hasNext, this throws NoSuchElementException
              if(filter.test(curr)) return curr;
          }
     }
     public boolean hasNext(){
         try{
             T item = get();
             inner = new AddFirst(item,inner);
             return true;
         }
         catch(NoSuchElementException e){
             return false;
         }
     }
}
class Map<K,T> implements MyStream<T>{
    MyStream<K> inner;
    Function<K,T> func;
    public Map(Function<K,T> func,MyStream<K> prev){
        this.func=func;
        inner = prev;
    }
    public T get(){
        return func.apply(inner.get());
    }
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return inner.hasNext();
    }
}
class Forall<T> implements Predicate<MyStream<T>>{
    Predicate<T> pred;
    public Forall(Predicate<T> func){
        pred=func;
    }
    public boolean test(MyStream<T> ms){
        while(ms.hasNext()){
            if(!pred.test(ms.get()) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
class Exists<T> implements Predicate<MyStream<T>>{
    Predicate<T> pred;
    public Forall(Predicate<T> func){
        pred=func;
    }
    public boolean test(MyStream<T> ms){
        while(ms.hasNext()){
            if(pred.test(ms.get()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
class Fork<T>{
    Deque<T> advance;
    MyStream<T> inner;
    boolean ahead;
    MyStream<T> master;
    MyStream<T> slave;
    public Fork(MyStrem<T> prev){
         inner=prev;
         advance= new LinkedList<T>();
         ahead=false;
         master = new ForkStream(true);
         slave = new ForkStream(false);
    }
    public MyStream<T> getMaster(){
        return master;
    }
    public Iterator<T> getMasterIter(){
        return master;
    }
    public MyStream<T> getSlave(){
        return slave;
    }
    public Iterator<T> getSlaveIter(){
        return slave;
    }
    class ForkStream implements MyStream<T>, Iterator<T>{
         boolean role;
         public ForkStream(boolean in){
             role=in;
         }
         public T get(){
              if(role==ahead||advance.size()==0){
                 ahead=role;
                 T item = inner.get();
                 advance.addLast(item);
                 return item;
              }
              else{
                  return advance.removeFirst();
              }
         }
         public boolean hasNext(){
               return (role!=ahead&&advance.size()!=0) || inner.hasNext();
         }
         public T next(){
               return get();
         }
    }
}
```

With these classes i could rewrite my methode as:

```
Stream<T> applyUntil(Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func,
  Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate){
    Fork<T> fork = new Fork(new Convert<T>(in.iterator()));
    Stream<T> master = StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(fork.getMasterIter(),0),false);
    Stream<T> slave = StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(fork.getSlaveIter(),0),false);
    if(predicate.test(master)) return slave
    return applyUntil(func.apply(slave,func,predicate);
}
```

which does work for infinite Streams, which is still lazy, which reuses calculated values. That looks for me like an all-in-one device suitable for every purpose.

**Edit:** When I tried to explain, why this last codeblock cannot compile, I found a way to make it compile. It's still not very good, loosing lots of stream-magic, is not Thread-Save etc. Additionally, MyStream should have a `close` method, to signal if your not longer interested in any data - so `Fork` doesn't have to save it for you. So another question came up in my head: Can you create a `j.u.stream.Stream from something like an iterator that tells its iterator it's not longer interested in any data (because of short-circuiting) ?

So my Question is: Does JDK8 without external Libaries have someting like my Fork, keeping more magic alive?
If Yes: Which class / methode can help me? 
If No: Why not? And: How could you implement it on your own, keeping as much magic as possible alive?

Thanks for reading, sorry for this long text :/
Alex

Comment: Thanks a lot for interesting question. I am in the middle of understanding what your solution does, do you mind update the code till compilable state? Ex: `fork.master` should be a `java.util.stream.Stream<T>`, the same for `.slave()`

Comment: @tkachuko When i tried to explain why this is impossible, i came up with a compiling version, you can see this one now. It's still not very good, and lead to another question - but at leat it does work now, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your analysis of the performance issue has to be corrected. In your second variant, it doesn’t matter how often `func.apply` is invoked, as that function doesn’t perform any work. All it does, is chaining another intermediate operation on a Stream that is later on processed, but it depends on that processing, how much performance impact it has.

In this regard, you are focusing too much on short-circuiting operations on large or even infinite streams, which happen to complete very early in your specific setup. The fundamental issue, that each of your filtering steps may potentially process all Stream elements and has to complete it before the next filtering step and that there is an unpredictable number of filtering steps, doesn’t change.

If you always use combinations of predicates and Stream elements that allow early short circuiting, it makes your third solution shine, but note that in these cases, the issue of your second solution is not the nested function application, but rather that you still collect the entire initial Stream into a `List` before that. When you skip that step and invoke the method accepting a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` in the first place, you don’t get these problems.

Then, buffering elements into a `Deque` or not, is a small trade-off depending of the weight of the actual intermediate operations you chain to the Stream. Note that you can do, what you do in the 3rd approach, with the Stream API, without mirroring it:

```
/** returns a {@code List} containing two {@code Stream}s */
public static <T> List<Stream<T>> fork(Stream<T> source) {
    Spliterator<T> srcSp=source.spliterator();
    ArrayDeque<T> deque=new ArrayDeque<>();
    Boolean[] ahead={ null };
    final class Branch extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> {
        private final Boolean type;
        Branch(Boolean b) {
            super(srcSp.estimateSize(), srcSp.characteristics());
            type=b;
        }
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if(deque.isEmpty() || ahead[0]==type) {
                if(!srcSp.tryAdvance(deque::push)) return false;
                ahead[0]=type;
                action.accept(deque.peek());
                return true;
            }
            action.accept(deque.removeLast());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(
        StreamSupport.stream(new Branch(true),  false),
        StreamSupport.stream(new Branch(false), false));
}
public static <T> Stream<T> applyUntil(
        Stream<T> in, Function<Stream<T>,Stream<T>> func, Predicate<Stream<T>> predicate) {
    List<Stream<T>> fork = fork(in);
    return predicate.test(fork.get(0))? fork.get(1):
        applyUntil(func.apply(fork.get(1)), func, predicate);
}
```

But as said, it only helps you in the small corner case of short-circuiting operations and unless you have really expensive intermediate operations, it’s not faster than your re-applying second approach, if you eliminate the initial collecting of the entire Stream into a `List`.

Comment: That's pretty much the solution i was looking for, thanks. But there are some questions left: do i have to `synchronize` tryAdvance? And: Can i somehow catch a "I'm not longer interested" signal, when a stream will never ask for any data again? Because otherwise this implementation will still store everything, although a terminal operation has been called on the returned Stream.

Comment: Since this creates two independent Streams, making them thread-safe is much more complicated than a simple `synchronized` statement. You have to ensure the access to the source, deque and ahead marker is consistently guarded by a shared lock (`this` is inappropriate) while the execution of the consumer’s `accept` method should happen without holding a lock. And there is no end signal to catch, Streams don’t report that. You could use on-close actions, but that would require explicit closing by your application code; Stream don’t do that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Java 9 will have [takeWhile](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [dropWhile](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-). Combine those with [Stream.concat](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) and you can do

```
Stream.concat(
  sourceCollection.stream().takeWhile(predicate).map(mapper), 
  sourceCollection.stream().dropWhile(predicate.negate())
)
```

This doesn't consume extra memory for an intermediate collection but will burn CPU time by traversing the prefix twice unless it can short-circuit before reaching the 2nd stream.

For a more efficient solution you can implement intermediate stateful operations, such as your conditional map function, by extracting `stream.spliterator()`, wrapping it into a custom subclass of `Spliterator` - or `j.u.Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator` if you're lazy about implementing parallelism support - and then using `j.u.s.StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator<T>, boolean)` to wrap it back into a stream.

Comment: imo `takeWhile` will take a `Predicate<T>`, but i'm looking for a "modify stream until" that takes a `Predicate<Stream<T>>` - so i don't understand how to use `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`in my circumstances.

Comment: The second sentence of my answer explains how to use it... which part is not clear?

Comment: For me your code looks like "map, as long predicate.test(item) returned true, don't modify the remaing stream". So you have a predicate testing items, and return a stream, wich is partially mapped.
I wanted to write something like "map, until predicate.test(stream) returns true. Then return stream." It should return a stream, wich might be mapped a thousend times (if mapped 999 times still didn't fit the predicate)

Comment: Ok, looks like I did not understand the intent of your question then. You mean you want to apply the mapping function to each item repeatedly until some condition is met, for that item? Because you can't really test anything on a whole stream without consuming it, i.e. you can't make decisions on the first item based on something that happens on a later item unless you capture the whole stream into a collection. Maybe you should write an example what you want to do in iterative style, i.e. with nested loops?

Comment: It seems like you're dealing with potentially two infinities here. Recursively applying the mapping function, possibly an infinite amount of times, to a potentially infinite amount of elements. Short-circuiting that is possible, but there are many different strategies you can try to do that (depth-first, breadth-first, balanced breadth/depth advances). Without knowledge of the underlying problem they may either fail to terminate or be needlessly inefficient.

Comment: For clarification: I want "the first infinity" to be calculated eagerly, and "the second infinity" to be calculated lazy. A few Examples: `mapUntil(Stream.of(1),x->x,x->false)` should not terminate.
`mapUntil(Stream.generate(()->1),x->2x, x->x.anyMatch(i->i==2))` should terminate, returning a stream of infinite 2's

Comment: Then you can simplify your problem by not applying the predicate to the whole stream but simply the first element, because your logic can only terminate when the condition can be fulfilled on the first element, since it would descend infinitely otherwise.

Comment: Well, looks like my question is not well thought out. `mapUntil(Stream.generate(()->1),x->2x,x->x.anyMatch(i->i==2))` cannot terminate (because `Stream.generate(()->1).anyMatch(i->i==2)` doesn't terminate. But your answer is wrong to: `mapUntil(Stream.iterate(1,x->x+1),x->2x,x->x.limit(50).allMatch(i->i%2==0)` should (really) return a stream of all even numbers. I'm sorry for the confusion.